# Parse XML from sdcard android

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, sd-card

I'm trying to read a xml file from sdcard. I need to parse it to a string array.

XML (a.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <string-array name="Timetable">
        <item>05:40</item>
        <item>06:00</item>
        <item>06:16</item>
        <item>06:28</item>
        <item>06:40</item>
        <item>07:16</item>
        <item>07:29</item> 
        <item>07:43</item>
        <item>07:55</item>
        <item>08:07</item>
        <item>08:22</item> 
        <item>08:34</item>
        <item>08:46</item>
        <item>08:58</item>
        <item>09:10</item>
        <item>09:22</item>
        <item>09:34</item>
        <item>09:46</item>        
        <item>12:10</item>
        <item>12:22</item>
        <item>12:34</item>
        <item>12:46</item>         
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I have tried to use two different functions, and none worked, the final string was empty.

Function 1:

```
 public void function(){
        String xml = null;
        try {           
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("FindMyBus/a.xml");

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Function2:

```
public void prueba(){
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "FindMyBus/a.xml");

        StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
        try {
              //use buffering, reading one line at a time
              //FileReader always assumes default encoding is OK!
              BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
              try {
                String line = null; //not declared within while loop
                /*
                * readLine is a bit quirky :
                * it returns the content of a line MINUS the newline.
                * it returns null only for the END of the stream.
                * it returns an empty String if two newlines appear in a row.
                */
                while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){
                  contents.append(line);
                  contents.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

                }
              }
              finally {
                input.close();
              }
            }
            catch (IOException ex){
              ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            String data= contents.toString();

    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to parse the xml file you need to use a xml parser. get it as seperate strings and then save it into a string array

Please follow this link to understand better

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

when you get the parsed string u can add it to the array.

Answer (score 0):

If your xml is in your application resources, like it seems to be, you can do:

```
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Timetable);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the xml is taken from a sd-card.